# Why I Shouldn't use Nothing in Place of Unit

Tags: scala

I was looking at the Scala's Hierarchy and then This click in my mind.

What if I declare the `None` like `Option[Unit]` and `Nil` like `List[Unit]`

What Exactly is the difference between Unit and Nothing?

What will happen If I start using Nothing in Place of Unit?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One difference is that the `Unit` type has exactly one value (`()`) and `Nothing` has none. So there's nothing that you can return from a `Nothing`-returning method, meaning that all legal methods with return type `Nothing` must either loop forever, throw an exception or otherwise never reach the regular end of the function.

Another difference is that `Nothing` is a subtype of every type and `Unit` is not.

> What if I declare the None like Option[Unit] and Nil like List[Unit]

Then you won't be able to use those values when creating lists or options of any type other than `Unit`.

> What will happen If I start using Nothing in Place of Unit?

Your code will no longer compile as your methods will try to return the wrong type.

Comment: Just to clarify @sepp2k answer (which is totally right), If you declare None as Option[Unit], then you cannot do: val none: Option[Int] = None, since Unit is not a subtype of Int

Answer (score 2):

There are no elements of type `Nothing`.

There is the only element of type `Unit`, namely `()`.

`Nothing` is a subtype of any type. Value of any type can be transformed to `Unit` type.

Comment: I Just updated the Question Can you also update the answer accordingly